# Sort Design In Php

Tags: php, design-patterns

[image]

I have designed the sorting mechanism for my site as :
Now due to change in requirement, I need to add some variables which are common to all Strategy i.e ByDate, ByConsuption, By Demand.

Also I need to modify the sorting string, based on output of a function
for example if a function returns available then,

1. SORT BY DATE DESC => sort by available desc, DATE desc
2. SORT BY DEMAND DESC => sort by available desc, DEMAND desc

**Question:**

If I have some common variables/functions how can I include at one point and still it can be accessible in all classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a SortStrategyBase or SortStrategyAbstract class which will would have the common functionality, and then have the factory inject whatever property is required. All SoryByWhateverStrategy classes would then extend the base/abstract.

Comment: So do u mean SortStrategyAbstract class should be used instead of interface ?

Comment: You can still have both, the interface to enforce a contract, and the abstract with some functionality. I'd keep the interface, because the abstract does enforce you to have at least some implementation. The abstract itself can then implement the interface (if it has all the required methods) or the classes can both extend the abstract and implement the interface.